# how do I test flyaway migration without creating a database locally?

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, database-migration, flyway

I wrote the migration using https://flywaydb.org/documentation/getstarted/advanced/java . Now I want to test this in test classes.

How is it possible to add old data -> perform migration in tests -> check that the data migrated correctly?

How else can I tell a test to perform a migration within a single test?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to test flyway migration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23324952/how-to-test-flyway-migration)

Comment: @crizzis obviously not, as the answer implies having a database locally

Comment: In addition to the suggestions on that link, take advantage of the VALIDATE command and the ability to migrate only after a validation.

Comment: As part of the test, how can I configure a configuration that will register in "locations" for flyway not only the standard "db/migrations" path, but also the path for my test migration?